# How to solve the triangulation problem?

Tags: trigonometry, systems-of-equations, triangulation

I have $3$ sensors. I've built the following system of equations that match the data from sensors. I need to find $x$, $y$, $R_a$, $R_b$, $R_c$, $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\gamma$. Can you please help me, or at least hint how can I solve this system.
\begin{align}A_x & = x+R_a\cos \alpha \\
A_y & = y+R_a\sin \alpha \\
B_x & = x+R_b\cos \beta \\
B_y & = y+R_b\sin \beta \\
C_x & = x+R_c\cos \gamma \\
C_y & = y+R_c\sin \gamma \\
R_b-R_a & = z_1 \\ 
R_c-R_a & = z_2
\end{align}

Comment: Welcome to MSE. If you haven't done so already, I suggest you take [the tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour), and that you read our guidelines for [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question), with emphasis on [providing context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960). Your post is simply a problem statement without any context at all, which on this site can quickly attract down votes and close votes. You can edit your post to add some context as suggested at those links.

Comment: You have a non-linear system of equations, your best bet is to use a numerical method, such as Newton's method. Look it up.

Comment: You can eliminate quite many variables among the eight.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: start with $R_b=z_1+R_a$. Then by rearranging the first two equations, squaring and adding, we can obtain: $R_a^2=(A-1)^2(x^2+y^2)$. Similarly, squaring and adding third and fourth equation, we get $(R_a+z_1)^2=(B-1)^2(x^2+y^2)$.

Thus, $$\left(\frac{R_a}{R_a+z_1}\right)^2=\left(\frac{A-1}{B-1}\right)^2$$

Comment: Sorry, I've made a mistake in formula writing. Ax should be treated as A with subtext x. $A_x$

Answer (score 2):

From a trigonometric identity, the values of $x$ and $y$ must satisfy these equations simultaneously:
$$x^2+y^2 = \frac{R_a^2}{(A-1)^2}$$
$$x^2+y^2 = \frac{R_b^2}{(B-1)^2}$$
$$x^2+y^2 = \frac{R_c^2}{(C-1)^2}.$$
The only way for three circles with the same center (in this case, the origin) to have any real intersection points is for the circles to be identical:  that is:
$$\frac{R_a^2}{(A-1)^2}=\frac{R_b^2}{(B-1)^2}=\frac{R_c^2}{(C-1)^2}.$$
From the second to last equation,
$$\left|\frac{B-1}{A-1}\right|R_a-R_a = z_1$$
$$\implies R_a = \frac{z_1}{\left|\frac{B-1}{A-1}\right|-1}.$$
Therefore,
$$R_b = z_1+\frac{z_1}{\left|\frac{B-1}{A-1}\right|-1},\quad R_c = z_2+\frac{z_1}{\left|\frac{B-1}{A-1}\right|-1}.$$
This should give you a good start.

As far as finding the angles $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$, I'm not sure at the moment.  Perhaps someone else can shed light on this.

Comment: Sorry, I've made a mistake in the question initially. $Ax$ should be treated as $A_x$